# Multiple iframe scroll on Chrome Android

Tags: css, html, iframe

At work, we have a system which enables to change some wbesite aspects of that system. We are trying to add modal boxes (3 of them) to the site. It works perfectly well on Windows based browsers. On mobile it doesn' work correctly. We have added a scroll bar element to iframe (which we use as we have character limit on the system) which scrolls on touch for first loaded iframe, but on other 2, the scroll only works using scrollbar not touch.

I know that using iframe is not ideal, but because of the character contraint, we can't add web content to the modal without paying system devs to change the limit and of course wait for them to complete the whole process.

Does anyone has a suggestion on how to resolve this problem?

HTML:

```
<a href="#privacy">Privacy Policy</a>&nbsp;<a href="#cookie">Cookie Policy</a>
<div id="privacy" class="modalDialog">
<div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a><iframe src="policies/fpn.html" frameBorder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe></div>
</div>
<div id="cookie" class="modalDialog">
<div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a><iframe src="policies/cookie.html" frameBorder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modalDialog iframe  { width: 100%;
height: 100%;}

.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;       

}

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto; 
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 80%;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;  
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    overscroll-behavior: contain;         

}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            width: 20px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
            box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}

.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 5px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

Comment: Hello could you please post the code that create the problem, or at least an example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution when I was searching for fix different issue.

By adding `display:block;` to target subclass and `display:none;` to parent class it has fixed the issue.